# Uniform convergence of  $\sum \frac{1}{n(x^2+n)}$

Tags: real-analysis

Find set  on which the series $\sum \frac{1}{n(x^2+n)}$ converge uniform. 
My solution is as follows
$|1/(x^2+n)|≤1$  so that  $|1/n(x^2+n)|\leq1/n$.
Since $\sum1/n$ converges  to zero as n goes to infinity , then by Weierstrass test the series converges uniform. Am I  in the right track?, I don’t know how I can get values of $x$  for which the given  series is uniform convergent. Thanks for any kind of help.

Comment: The [harmonic series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)) $\sum 1/n$ is the classic example of a series that doesn't converge, despite its terms approaching zero.

Comment: @neemy: I used LaTeX to type the equation. Check if this is what you would like to ask.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that $\sum\frac{x^2+n}{n}$ is intended.

Comment: I agree with André. Did you mean $\sum\frac{1}{n(x^2 + n)}$? About your reasoning: you have $x^2 + n \geq 1$, and so $(x^2 + n)/n \geq 1/n$, which is the opposite of what you have. What does that suggest?

Comment: @Dylan: Maybe I made a mistake when I edited the post. I am sorry.

Comment: @Paul Don't be! I think what you typeset was the only available interpretation of the symbols that were there.

Comment: If it is indeed $\frac{1}{n(x^2+n)}$, applying the $M$-test should work well.

Comment: @neemy: Please try to write formulas correctly and unambiguously.  Your second version was a little better, but "$1/a(b)$" does not make it clear whether you want $\frac{1}{ab}$ or $\frac{1}{a}\cdot b$.  Please either use LaTeX fractions, e.g. `$\frac{1}{n(x^2+n)}$` to render $\frac{1}{n(x^2+n)}$, or use parentheses correctly, e.g. 1/(n(x^2+n)), until you get the hang of LaTeX.

Comment: Just taking a look at $\zeta(2)$ would also help.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The estimate ${1\over x^2+n}\le 1$ is "too much"; you are throwing away a term that actually helps you (the $n$). Estimate with ${1\over x^2+n}\le {1\over n}$ instead.